# set both title and text of circle on d3 not working

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple bubble chart that I need both text on a mouseover and text on the item for.  I can do one or the other but not both. The text shows up but I get no mouseOver title.

```
 node
 .append("text").text(function(d) { return  d.key; })
 .append("svg:title").text(function(d) { return d.AgtName; });
```

[sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/jwaldner/eumcfghk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the title is being appended to the text.

Try this:

```
 node
 .append("text").text(function(d) { return  d.key; });

 node
 .append("svg:title").text(function(d) { return d.AgtName; });
```

This should work.